# How to list NTFS's Alternate Data Stream Files using Java

Tags: java, file-listing, alternate-data-stream

I want to list NTFS alternate data stream file in a given directory using java. I can do this with the dir /R command on cmd, but I want to do it programmatically.

When I do normal file listing operations, I cannot list alternate data streams in the $Data style.

Answer (score 4):

This sample code is modeled after Oracles sample code in [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html).

It lists the files and directories in the current directory together with the alternate data streams.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserDefinedFileAttributeView;

public class Xd2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get(".");
        Files.list(p).forEach(file -> {
            UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.
                    getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
            try {
                // print file size and name
                System.out.printf("%8d %s%n", Files.size(file) , file);
                for (String name : view.list()) {
                    // list alternate data stream size and name
                    System.out.format("  %8d  %s\n", view.size(name), name);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in Java for this. I am afraid you should do it yourself. It is possible to call a `dir /R` command and parse output or make a JNI library to call system functions like `NtQueryInformationFile`.